# some mistake for Programming a Chatroom in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/LiNNN/96edrLno/   << It's my fiddle

I had something wrong, but I don't know what is the mistake
I want to design a ChatRoom's layout like this >> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXqFE.jpg)
somebody chat in here ,if user enter a lot text in chat block and the typesetting will over my chat area
in principle the chat area will follow chat block to expand
but it didn't and I dont know why -> It's Q1

when the user submits a quite long message to the chat ,the message gets outside of the chat block and it doesn't seem to break line between each two messages .

How to reach this?I don't know where my CSS went wrong

```js
function runScript(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    var chatDiv = document.getElementById("Chat");
                    var input = document.getElementById("inputText");
                    chatDiv.innerHTML = chatDiv.innerHTML + "<span class=\"myWord\">" + input.value + "</span><br /><br /><br/>";
                    input.value = "";
                }

            }
```

```css
#Chat {
        border-radius: 45px;
        margin:20px;
        padding:20px;
        border:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        background-color:#bbb9b9;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    div.othersText {
        max-width:80%;
        padding:20px;
        margin-top:25px;
        margin-bottom:25px;
        }
    div.myText {
        max-width:80%;
        padding:20px;

        text-align:right;
        margin-top:25px;
        margin-bottom:25px;
        }

    span.myWord{
        border-radius: 45px;
        border:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        background-color:#E9EBEE;
        padding:15px;
        color:#ab0af1;
        max-width:80%;
        float:right;
        clear:both;
    }

    span.othersWord{
        float:left;
        clear:both;
        border-radius: 45px;
        border:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        background-color:#E9EBEE;
        padding:15px;
        max-width:80%;
        color:#3B5998;
    }
    #textInput{
        text-align: center;
    }

    #textInput input{
        width: 90%;
        height: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="Chat">
                <div class="othersText"><span class="othersWord">Johnny:The air quality in this city is horrendous! The pollution levels were so high that we all need to wear a face mask when we go outside. </span></div>
                <div class="myText"><span class="myWord">Exhaust fumes from vehicles cause a great deal of damage to the environment.</span></div>
                <div class="othersText"><span class="othersWord">Johnny:On top of that, there are a few large chemical factories in the suburbs, which are contributing to the high pollution levels in the water and the air in this city.</span></div>
                <div class="myText"><span class="myWord">As much as I love this city, I think I'm going to have to find a greener city to live in. Living in a polluted city like this just can't be good for my health. </span></div>
                <div class="othersText"><span class="othersWord"> Johnny:I know what you mean. However, there are so few places left that have not been affected by global warming. If it's not the pollution, then it's the natural disasters, deforestation, or the greenhouse effect. </span></div>
                <div class="myText"><span class="myWord"> What is the greenhouse effect exactly?  </span></div>
                <div class="othersText"><span class="othersWord">Johnny:It's the gradual rise in the earth's temperature. </span></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: can you please add a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but try to add overflow: hidden; to your #Chat element.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

you could add `height: 400px; overflow-y: scroll` to #Chat element style.